# Maximization over a set of multifunctions (correspondences)

Tags: probability-theory, optimization

Here is my question:

Let $I = \{ h : [0,1]\Rightarrow P([0,1]) \}$ be the set of multifunctions (correspondences) from $[0,1]$ to $ P([0,1])$ which is the set of probability measures over $[0,1]$.

For $n\in 1,2,\dots$ let $I_n = \{ h_n : \frac{1}{n} [0,n-1] \Rightarrow P(\frac{1}{n} [0,n-1]) \}$.

Let $f : I\to \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to show that for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $n$ big enough such that $arg \max_{I} f - \epsilon \leq arg \max_{I_n} f$.

I'm not sure about the hypotheses one should put on $f$.

The idea is that if $f$ were a function from $I = [0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, let's say continuous, and $I_n$ a regular subdivision of $[0,1]$ in $n$ intervals, this would be true. I would like a similar result in this context.

Thank you very much,

Cheers